# Dynamic Email attachment using Logic Apps via Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-logic-apps

I need to build a generic Logic app using which i can send mail with attachment.
Is this possible to pass path and file name as parameter so i can use same logic app for different ADF pipelines.

Comment: Where is the file stored ?  can you give sample path of the file ?

Comment: file is stored in ADLS container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course we can use a generic with a generic logic app. You just need to set the "**When a HTTP request is received**" trigger with two parameters, we can do it by specify the schema of it(shown like below).

**schema:**

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "path": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "fileName": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

In following actions of your logic app, you can use the parameters `path` and `fileName` when you get the file from Azure Data Lake.
[image]

Then you can use the logic app in Azure Data Factory by a "**Web**" activity.

[image]